# How to programmatically load Xtext projects with cross project dependencies

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I have a use case where I start with two projects A and B in my eclipse workspace. Using project properties I add Project A as a dependency to Project B, then in project B I am able to use namespace imports to reference other packages defined in Project A and opening it in the editor those cross project dependencies are nicely resolved.

What I want to do is figure out how to load these Xtext projects on the server-side where its running Equinox and the two projects are on the file system at a known location. I can easily traverse both projects to get DSL scripts but how would I resolve the dependency project B has on A? The way I currently go about this without cross project dependencies is creating a single XText Resource Set and load all the DSL scripts in the project. In this case would I use the same approach by adding all DSL scripts from Project A and B into the same resource and the dependencies will resolve or is there a different way to go about this?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: filesystem does not know anything about projects.
thus you have to figure out what the projects are and to traverse these yourself

Comment: If I serialize/deserialize the files myself can I put them in a resource set together and have the cross project dependencies be resolved?

Comment: there are no projects in standalone mode. there is just a pile that is called "resourceset" and if you fill that up with all resources that should see each other it should work

Comment: Thanks @ChristianDietrich !!